# Using $group in aggregate Spring Data equivalent

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Following is the MongoDB query. I am stuck on finding the right Spring API equivalent for the group and project.

```
  db.users.aggregate([ 
      { $lookup: { from: "organizations", localField: "orgId", 
foreignField: "_id", as:"organization" } }, 
{$unwind: "$organization"},
 { $group: { _id: "$userOrgMap.orgId", userCount: { $sum: 1 }, name: { "$first": "$organization.name"}, status: { "$first": "$organization.status"}, },
 {$project:{ _id:1, name:1, status:1, userCount :1 } }, { $sort:{userCount:-1} } ]);
```

Need help to provide details on the Spring Data MongoDB API which needs to be used for the $group and $project pipelines

Comment: Please add the current spring aggregation code that you have tried along with your input and output pojo classes. This will help you get a good answer.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations

Comment: I found that the query is wrong. There are organizations without users. So this query will ignore organizations without users.